# Intermittent outage on a single breaker (no trips, no GFI)

Tags: electrical, circuit

I have an entire circuit that lost power 3 weeks ago.  No surge, no tripped breakers, just went to turn on the light and nothing.  This circuit powers the master bedroom and bathroom on the 2nd floor.  No power to every light/outlet on the circuit.  15A circuit, Cutler-Hammer panel, low load on the circuit.

Here's what I've done:

- Removed/reinstalled the existing breaker.  Result = still dead.
- Swapped breaker with 15A breaker below it in the panel (kept the hots connected). Result = dead breaker still dead, good breaker still good.
- Swapped the hots between the two breakers.  Result = hot for the dead circuit still dead, hot for the good circuit still good.
- Moved the dead breaker to an empty slot in the panel.  Result = still dead.
- Installed brand new CH15 breaker in the original slot.  Result = still dead.
- Checked every outlet, all push-in connections were moved to the side screws.  Replaced some of the old '80s beige plugs with new ones.  Result = still dead.
- Checked every light switch, all wires/pigtails were re-joined and re-capped.  Result = still dead.

This circuit does not have a GFI plug.  The GFI in the master bath connects to the GFI in the hall bath and, therefore, still had power through this.  I saw no evidence of heat, spark, or burn on any of the outlets or switches.  I tested for opens or polarity issues, all the plugs were dead.  I turned this breaker off and left it.

This circuit was down for 5 days and the night before I was going to call an electrician, I turned the breaker back on and it worked.  Full power to the circuit like nothing was ever wrong.  This lasted for about 9 days then the circuit was dead again.  Before the circuit went down the second time I checked for open/polarity issues at the plugs and there were none.

Observations = trying to think of any commonalities between the first time it died and the second, I noticed a day or two before each power loss that when I would turn on a light (like a vanity light) it would subtly flicker for a few seconds at first.  That's how I knew to expect the power loss the second time.  Another observation, both times the circuit died was after consistent/extensive rain.  This may be incidental, since it never stops raining in WA, but observation nonetheless.  Also, I did have my meter replaced with a "smart" meter but that was back in early Nov and I only have a problem on 1 circuit out of 28.

I'm stumped y'all.  My next move is to use a tracer/probe to check for continuity but that will have to wait for a day off.  Seems strange that the line between the panel and the first outlet would break, then fix itself, then break again.  It bugs me that I can't solve this.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea how the circuit flows through the house? It could be one long run, or it could have multiple splits. If it runs through the attic or crawlspace, maybe there is a hidden junction box somewhere? Maybe a receptacle you never use is early in the circuit and causing the problems?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact  Unsure at this time.  I know where the last plug is in the circuit, and I believe I know where the first is (it's actually a light switch).  I believe the line runs through the joists in the ceiling above the 1st floor and below the 2nd floor.  I hope to find out with the tracer/probe.

Comment: It sounds like a broken wire somewhere, that is just broken like it has been cut.  Due to changes near it, the two broken ends either come together enough to make contact or separate.

Comment: Are the backstabs used on any of the outlets or switches?

Comment: @JACK Some of the outlets before were wired with backstabs but I replaced those outlets and wired them using the side screws.

Comment: You might want to check all the outlets and switches because you can't be sure of how the wiring is routed. A faulty backstab can definitely cause your problem.

Comment: I took another look at the panel, the wire from this circuit coming in to the panel is 14/3 (b/r/w/ground) where the red is the positive for this circuit and the black is for the next circuit down in the panel (shared negative and ground to the bus).  I'm hoping I can find the box where this wire splits to two 14/2 and that will be the source of my problem.

Comment: Please _carefully_ take the cover off of your panel and get us clear, focused pics of the 2 breakers sharing this cable. Also, just for good measure, include pics of all the labeling in the panel (especially the manufacturer's name/model info), and an overall pic of the breakers in the panel.

Comment: Problem is resolved.  I don't know how much this will help anyone in the future, but here's what happened... The 14/3 coming out of the panel went straight to a smoke alarm box on the 2nd floor ceiling.  From there it split to two 14/2 lines - the red hot to the down circuit and the black hot to the other good circuit upstairs.  I recently changed out all the smoke alarms upstairs and in doing so I must have jiggled the red hot enough to loosen the connection.  Once I re-twisted and capped it, everything on the bad circuit worked.  Thanks for the help.